# Space Gap on mobile devices

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm designing a Wordpress website with Enfold theme for one of my clients and I'm getting a strange space gap only on mobile devices.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

The website is:

http://pishdad.org

Thank you so much

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Alexandru Marica
>   I've noticed that you fixed it. How did you do it?

I used this CSS code

```
#wrap_all { position: relative !important; }
body {
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable *WP Rocket Plugin*.
Clearly at first inspect you can see it is the cause...
Probably you did not implement it correctly.

Comment: i disabled WP Rocket Plugin and checked setting but the problem is still exist

Comment: I've noticed that you fixed it. How did you do it?

Comment: I used this CSS code

#wrap_all { position: relative !important; }
body {
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}